# haproxy with xinetd shows warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer

Tags: mysql, mariadb, haproxy, xinetd

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-haproxy-as-load-balancer-for-mariadb-on-centos-7/#:~:text=MariaDB%20Galera%20Cluster%20supports%20the,incoming%20requests%20to%20all%20databases.) to setup a HAProxy server with a Galera clustering of 2 MariaDB servers; therefore, HAProxy, frontend and backend are working well except I got this warning message below. What's wrong? or how can I get rid of this warning?

tail -f /var/log/messages

```
Jun  5 17:15:43 mariadb-01 xinetd[105173]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:44 mariadb-01 xinetd[105177]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:45 mariadb-01 xinetd[105181]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:46 mariadb-01 xinetd[105185]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:47 mariadb-01 xinetd[105189]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:48 mariadb-01 xinetd[105193]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:49 mariadb-01 xinetd[105197]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:50 mariadb-01 xinetd[105201]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:51 mariadb-01 xinetd[105205]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:52 mariadb-01 xinetd[105209]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:53 mariadb-01 xinetd[105213]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:54 mariadb-01 xinetd[105217]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:55 mariadb-01 xinetd[105221]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:56 mariadb-01 xinetd[105225]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:57 mariadb-01 xinetd[105229]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:15:58 mariadb-01 xinetd[105233]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:16:00 mariadb-01 xinetd[105237]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:16:01 mariadb-01 xinetd[105241]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:16:02 mariadb-01 xinetd[105245]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:16:03 mariadb-01 xinetd[105249]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
Jun  5 17:16:04 mariadb-01 xinetd[105253]: warning: can't get client address: Connection reset by peer
```

Here are my mysqlchk file

```
[root@mariadb-01 ~]# cat /etc/xinetd.d/mysqlchk 
# default: on
# description: mysqlchk
service mysqlchk
{
    log_type = FILE /var/log/clustercheck.log
    disable = no
    flags = REUSE
    socket_type = stream
    port = 9200
    wait = no
    user = nobody
    server = /usr/bin/clustercheck
    log_on_failure += USERID
    log_on_success  =
    only_from = 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0
    per_source = UNLIMITED
}
```

haproxy.cfg

```
global
    maxconn         100
    log         /var/run/log    local0  info
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy.socket level admin  expose-fd listeners
    uid         80
    gid         80
    nbproc          1
    nbthread            1
    hard-stop-after     15m
    chroot              /tmp/haproxy_chroot
    daemon
    server-state-file /tmp/haproxy_server_state

listen HAProxyLocalStats
    bind 127.0.0.1:2200 name localstats
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats refresh 1
    stats admin if TRUE
    stats show-legends
    stats uri /haproxy/haproxy_stats.php?haproxystats=1
    timeout client 5000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout server 5000

frontend frontend-mariadb
    bind            0.0.0.0:3306 name 0.0.0.0:3306   
    mode            tcp
    log         global
    option          log-separate-errors
    option          tcplog
    timeout client      30000
    default_backend backend-mariadb_ipvANY

backend backend-mariadb_ipvANY
    mode            tcp
    id          102
    log         global
    option          log-health-checks
    balance         leastconn
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    server          mariadb-01 10.20.30.106:3306 id 104 check inter 1000 port 9200
    server          mariadb-02 10.20.30.107:3306 id 105 check inter 1000 port 9200
```

When I telnet to one of Mariadb, it shows this but there is no warning message in /var/log/messages

```
[root@client ~]# telnet 10.20.30.106 9200
Trying 10.20.30.106...
Connected to 10.20.30.106.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close
Content-Length: 40

Percona XtraDB Cluster Node is synced.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: what's in `ERR_FILE` of the `clustercheck` script and what's in `/var/log/clustercheck.log`? Can you add `+HOST` and remove `+USERID` to `log_on_failure` to see from which host the requests are, just a wild guess.

Comment: There is nothing for ERR_FILE even I set 
`ERR_FILE="/var/log/clustercheck.log"` in clusterchk.sh; and in mysqlchk I changed to `log_on_failure += HOST` but it is still the same.